# How can one change a P4 client using p4perl

Tags: perforce

Perorce on RHEL6:  Rev. P4/LINUX26X86_64/2011.1/393975 (2011/12/16).

In a perl script using p4perl, I would like to change the current client knowing only the linux directory that I am moving to.

So I run the perl script in /proj/me/workarea and I'm able to connect to the client using...

```
use P4;
our $p4 = new P4;
$p4->disconnect();
$p4->SetCwd($ENV{PWD});
$p4->connect();
```

But now I move to a new dir which maps to a different P4 client.  Lets call it "/proj/me/different_workarea".  I need to move there anyway, so I..

```
chdir("/proj/me/diffent_workarea");
```

But the attempt to make a new P4 connection to this new area using the code above fails.  It just reconnects to the original dir/client, not the new one.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

`chdir()` doesn't update `$PWD` -- you'll need to either update it yourself, or not rely on its value.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sam Stafford says, `chdir()` doesn't update `$PWD`. Both p4perl and the `p4` binary (if you were to invoke it as a sub-process) detect the current working directory from `$PWD`, rather then calling `getcwd()` from Perl's `Cwd` module (or the `getcwd` system call).

The most elegant solution to this that I've found is to call `use Cwd qw(chdir);`. It turns out that the `Cwd` module has its own variant of the `chdir()` function, which does update the `$PWD` variable. In fact, the documentation for `Cwd` [explicitly states this](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/PathTools-3.74/Cwd.pm#$ENV%7BPWD%7D):

> #### $ENV{PWD}
>
> If you ask to override your chdir() built-in function,
>
> ```
> use Cwd qw(chdir);
> ```
>
> then your PWD environment variable will be kept up to date. Note that it will only be kept up to date if all packages which use chdir import it from Cwd.

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

```
use P4;
our $p4 = new P4;   <----------   
$p4->disconnect();
$p4->SetCwd($ENV{PWD});
$p4->connect();
```

Comment: it's not clear what you fixed. This snippet is the same as in the original description. You highlight the `new` call, but that was already there.

Comment: Oh, ya, the snippet is the same, but in the real code, the "$p4 = new P4" was originally global, declared once and intended to be reused.  A subroutine did the disconnect->SetCwd->connect.  The change I made was to (re)create $p4 inside the subroutine... effectively reinventing it each time.  
                                  
I'll try the "use Cwd qw(chdir);" (I like it better) and use it if it works.